# EPERM error in nodejs when calling execSync

Tags: io, electron

In my Electron app in Windows (which I believe uses node.js or io.js under the hood?), I've got the following line of code which is problematic:

`var ipconfigOutput = child_process.execSync("ipconfig").toString();`

This code works without issue when I run the app via command line, e.g. `electron .`.

However, I'm running into a problem after packaging my application. When I build the app using `electron-packager`, this code works just fine if I invoke the built `exe` file from the command line. *However*, if I run the program by double-clicking the built `exe` within Windows Explorer, I get the following error:

`Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, write`

Why is this error occurring, and how should I change the above code?

I imagine it is due to a difference in how stdout works when a process is started via the command line vs. when it is started via Explorer, but I don't understand IO well enough to know what is going wrong here.

Comment: Administrative privileges? Working directory?

Comment: Hi Amit, I thought about that as well -- I tried running as Admin and I still get the issue. I don't think it has anything to do with the working directory because I ran the command via `cmd` one directory above, and I don't get the error. The only thing I can think of is that it has something to do with how stdout works when you invoke an exe from explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I can get the code to work by changing it to

`var ipconfigOutput = child_process.spawnSync("ipconfig").stdout.toString();`

However, I am not sure *why* `spawnSync` works now and `execSync` did not. If anyone could comment, that'd be great!